# Why does Await within "override async void OnPaint" throw OutOfMemoryException or ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working with some existing code and trying to convert a graphics system in a WinForms app from sequential to concurrent.  So far so good, I pretty well have everything converted and working with async Task / awaits added throughout the application.  This ultimately leads back to `override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)`.  I can simply change `void` to `async void` and that will allow me to compile and go on my merry way.  However, in running tests to simulate delays have run into some behavior I do not understand.

See the following code.

```
protected override async void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    await PaintAsync(e);
}

private async Task<Color> ColorAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);  //throws ArgumentException - Parameter is not valid
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);    //works

    Color color = Color.Blue;

    //this also throws
    //color = await Task<Color>.Run(() => 
    //{
    //    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    //    return Color.Red;
    //});

    return color;
}

private async Task PaintAsync(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //await Task.Delay(1000);   //throws OutOfMemoryException 
    //Thread.Sleep(1000);       //works

    try
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        PointF start = new PointF(121.0F, 106.329636F);
        PointF end = new PointF(0.9999999F, 106.329613F);

        using (Pen p05 = new Pen(await ColorAsync(), 1F))
        {
            p05.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Custom;
            p05.DashPattern = new float[] { 4, 2, 1, 3 };
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(p05, start, end);
        }

        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comments included in code to show problematic lines.  `OnPaint()` has been made async, it then waits on `PaintAsync()` to complete.  This is important because without the await it will crash.  The graphics context will be disposed before `PaintAsync` is complete.  So far so good, everything makes sense.

To simulate a delay I then added `await Task.Delay` to the `PaintAsync` routine, to simulate some work being done.  This throws an `OutOfMemoryException`.  Why?  The system is not out of memory.  Also, if relevant, I'm compiling as x64.  This made me think GDI+ doesn't like a delay, maybe there is a minimum threshold in which it needs to be accessed or Windows destroys the handle??  So I try `Thread.Sleep()` instead to see if any difference.  It works.  There is a 1sec pause then the line is drawn.  I then repeat this same test but using a subroutine called by `PaintAsync`, `ColorAsync()`.  This time `ArgumentException` is the error.  I assume behind the scenes it's all the same cause.

What is going on here?  It seems there is something fundamental I do not understand.

Instead of having a delay I tried adding an `await Task.Run()` inside the `ColorAsync` (shown commented out), and interestingly this throws as well.  Why?  This makes me think `OnPaint` does not want to await on anything, like there is a context switching issue.  But it doesn't mind await on `PaintAsync`.  Or await on `ColorAsync` from `PaintAsync`.  But if I await on `Task.Run` a problem?

How can I await from `OnPaint` without these exceptions?

**Edit 1**

Here is an additional example to illustrate my confusion and help people understand what I'm asking.  The following appears to work flawlessly.

```
protected override async void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    await PaintAsync2(e);
}

private async Task<Color> ColorAsync()
{
    Color color = Color.Blue;

    color = await Task<Color>.Run(() =>
    {
        return Color.Red;
    });

    return color;
}

private async Task PaintAsync2(PaintEventArgs old)
{
    using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
    {
        var e = new PaintEventArgs(g, old.ClipRectangle);

        try
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            PointF start = new PointF(121.0F, 106.329636F);
            PointF end = new PointF(0.9999999F, 106.329613F);

            using (Pen p05 = new Pen(await ColorAsync(), 1F))
            {
                p05.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Custom;
                p05.DashPattern = new float[] { 4, 2, 1, 3 };
                g.DrawLine(p05, start, end);
            }

            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Why does this work, but not the first version?  Comments suggest that the first version fails because by doing an await I am changing context to a different non-UI thread, blowing out the graphics context passed into OnPaint().  So in the second version I ignore the context passed to the OnPaint routine and do a CreateGraphics to establish a new graphics context.  However, as stated in the MSFT documentation, the rules are the same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.creategraphics?view=netframework-4.7.2

CreateGraphics() is threadsafe, allowing a graphics context to be established on non-UI threads.  However, that context can only be accessed from the thread in which it was created.  So, if awaiting on some other Task causes a threading context change, shouldn't I still get the same error?  ColorAsync spins up a Task, which runs on a separate thread, that returns Color.Red and awaits on it.  That color is then passed to the graphics context, etc.  But it works.

Why does one work, but not the other?  Also, is doing things this way with CreateGraphics() a bad design?  Even though this is working, is there some reason I should not do this that I'll regret?  Say I use OnPaint to asynchronously trigger a bunch of background threads, each responsible for rendering different aspects of the UI.  Each opening their own graphics context, etc.  As far as I can tell this should not lock the UI up, right?  Architecturally I can think of a number of reasons why I wouldn't want to do this.  Without getting into all those specifics though, just focused on the simple principle-driven questions at hand, what's wrong with this?

**Edit 2**

Here is my theory.  What does the code that invokes Control.OnPaint look like?  Something like this perhaps?

```
using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
{
    var clip = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);
    var args = new PaintEventArgs(g, clip);

    if (OnPaint != null)
    {
        OnPaint(args);
    }
}
```

All I can figure is that if OnPaint is "async void" then it will return before completing, in which case g.Dispose() will be called at the end of using and then the context will be destroyed.  However, by calling CreateGraphics within PaintAync2, I am creating a new graphics context that is guaranteed to remain open...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186075/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-why-does-await-within-override-async-void-onpa).

Comment: Yes , Edit2 gives the explanation. But it is not a good solution. Don't try to make Windows async, it is a few million lines of backward compatible single threaded (and single minded) code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My Edit 2 is the answer.  I'm not sure why people need to get on soap boxes, make assumptions, and tell you how everything you're doing is wrong (even though they have no idea what you're intending to do) rather than just answering the plain question that's being asked.  All I was trying to do was understand the source of the error, not get into a big design pattern debate.  Most of the comments being posted were wrong.  Await was not switching to a different thread context.

After getting frustrated with the comments I decided to see if there is source available for System.Windows.Forms.Control.  Turns out there is.  Which I didn't know, and this is a huge help.

See this

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/control.cs

And this

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/PaintEvent.cs,1b5e97abf89104c1

From the source, here is the caller for Control.OnPaint

PaintEventArgs is created from dc

```
pevent = new PaintEventArgs(dc, clip);
```

And then wrapped in using(), which means after PaintWithErrorHandling returns it will be destroyed.  PaintWithErrorHandling is what calls OnPaint.

```
using (pevent)
{
    try
    {
        if ((m.WParam == IntPtr.Zero) && GetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint) || doubleBuffered)
        {
            PaintWithErrorHandling(pevent, PaintLayerBackground);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Looking at PaintEventArgs we see Graphics is instantiated when accessed.

```
public System.Drawing.Graphics Graphics
{
    get
    {
        if (graphics == null && dc != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            oldPal = Control.SetUpPalette(dc, false /*force*/, false /*realize*/);
            graphics = Graphics.FromHdcInternal(dc);
            graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
            savedGraphicsState = graphics.Save(); // See ResetGraphics() below
        }
        return graphics;
    }
}
```

and then subsequently destroyed when Dispose is called

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        //only dispose the graphics object if we created it via the dc.
        if (graphics != null && dc != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            graphics.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Since the override is marked async void, it will return before completed and the graphics context is destroyed.  It was confusing, however, because it was not crashing without the await but with Thread.Sleep.  The reason for this is that an async function will execute synchronously if it does not await on anything.  Even though OnPaint was awaiting PaintAsync, because PaintAsync did not await, all the way back down the line it was executing synchronously.  This has been an interesting revelation for me.  I was under the impression that a function marked async without awaits would execute synchronously, but only in the context of that function.  Any async functions that wait on this function would execute it asynchronously, but that is not the case.

For example, the following code.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    PaintAsync(e);

    Debug.WriteLine("done painting");
}

private async Task PaintAsync(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Visual studio puts a green line under the PaintAsync method which reads, "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously."

And then inside the OnPaint function, where PaintAsync is called, another green line with a warning that reads, "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call."

Based on the warnings, I would expect PaintAsync (within the context of that function) to execute synchronously.  Meaning the thread will block while waiting for Thread.Sleep.  I would then expect OnPaint to return immediately before PaintAsync completes.  This does not happen, however.  Everything executes as if synchronous.

The following code executes synchronously as well.

```
protected override async void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    await PaintAsync(e);

    Debug.WriteLine("done painting");
}

private async Task PaintAsync(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Even though I have added "async void" and "await" to OnPaint, everything executes exactly the same... because there is no new Task being awaited anywhere down the line.

I would call this out as a bug in Visual Studio's intellisense. It states that things will execute asynchronously in OnPaint, but that's not true.

Comment: Visual Studio never claimed that your last sample will execute asynchronously, it just isn't 100% confident that it will execute synchronously and therefore doesn't show the warning. There's also a big misunderstanding generally about how await works. The await keyword by itself doesn't make anything async, as you discovered. It's only async when the task returned from the method is not complete when the await executes. Since PaintAsync is actually synchronous, when the await keyword is run in OnPaint the task is already complete and the task does NOT yield the thread.

Comment: Right.  And this is why it's important to trace our misunderstood behavior.  I learned a lesson, but very different from the one I was expecting.  I am now using Task.Yield() to force a continuation.  And it's making me realize I have code all over the place that is assumed to be async but is probably not yielding when I think it is, so am going to do a review of everything.  I am undecided on whether I like this behavior or not.

Comment: What I didn't realize is I figured the framework was tacitly executing a Task.Yield() right off the bat.  What this means is that execution is synchronous up to the point of the first yield.  Always.  So I undoubtedly have a lot of code where I'm expecting an immediate return, but it's running sync in the child method doing whatever tasks until that method yields through an await.  Seems like any async method that might be called by a non-async source should yield immediately to prevent its callers from blocking.

Comment: async-await isn't designed to be a parallel programming model, it's designed to improve throughput of highly concurrent IO-bound code by reducing context switches. In such cases yielding when there's CPU bound work only hurts performance. I once saw a great blog post with a diagram that helped explain it, but I searched for 15 minutes and couldn't find it :( Anyway, it's great that you have better understanding now, but again I want to warn that it's purpose is not for parallel computation. It can be used to do so, but there are these gotcha's. Sometimes traditional multithreading is better.

Comment: [I found it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod)! :) Although you seem to understand it well enough now that it probably doesn't help. Also FYI, if you're trying to do parallel processing with task based async, you can use [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.2) to immediately start a delegate as a task, rather than calling Task.Yield at the beginning of each task you want to run in parallel.

Comment: @zivkan, great link, thanks. In my case I'm not trying to do parallel processing.  This is all UI work.  It's a highly interactive UI that is drawn out from scratch.  Some things can be pre-calculated on threads in the background.  But on the whole stuff reacts to user input and needs to be responsive.  That being said some of the drawing logic is math intensive and things get bogged down running sync.  That being the case it speeds things up a lot to throw certain blocks of logic into a Task.Run that gets awaited, forcing elements into subthreads and taking advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: @zivkan, the way this started out, which I suppose is pretty typical.  Is I had this existing codebase and started deep in the code trying to optimize a certain element.  I made a few routines async that were doing some large sorting work from collections.  But then in an effort to avoid doing .Result and .Wait() because of the deadlock pitfalls, I started making the routines which called my async routines async as well.  One things leads to another and I end up making hundreds of functions async and then it all ends up boiling down to OnPaint, lol.